# How can I use Database Helper class in CardView Adapter in android

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, adapter, android-cardview

I have use `ViewPager` and this `ViewPager` to set `CardView` display the card about the person name and person images so I can use the helper class in adapter and set the person image to card and also name so how can use this..
**.I am new to Android programming please solve this problem.**

**CardPagerAdapter**

```
 private List<CardView> mViews;
private List<String> mData;
private float mBaseElevation;

public CardPagerAdapter() {

    mData = new ArrayList<>();
    mViews = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        mData.add("");
        mViews.add(null);
    }
}

public float getBaseElevation() {
    return mBaseElevation;
}

@Override
public CardView getCardViewAt(int position) {
    return mViews.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.viewpager_adapter, container, false);
    container.addView(view);
    CardView cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cv);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivPeopelImage);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ak_image);

    if (mBaseElevation == 0) {
        mBaseElevation = cardView.getCardElevation();
    }

    cardView.setMaxCardElevation(mBaseElevation * MAX_ELEVATION_FACTOR);
    mViews.set(position, cardView);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
    mViews.set(position, null);
}
```

**Viewpage Class**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alertme);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    mCardAdapter = new CardPagerAdapter();
    mCardShadowTransformer = new ShadowTransformer(mViewPager, mCardAdapter);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCardAdapter);
    mViewPager.setPageTransformer(false, mCardShadowTransformer);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
}
```

Comment: Just send id via constructor in your adapter.

Comment: Okay i will try @xAqweRx

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a POJO class (as your requirement) example: yourclass

2) Create object for yourclass and store in a list, and store it in list.
as follows.

ArrayList listObject=new ArrayList();

3) mCardAdapter = new CardPagerAdapter(listObject);